# Network unreachable error + can't add Gateway IP

Tags: raspbian, wifi, wireless, networking

I'm having the exact same problem as the poster of this question: ["connect: Network is unreachable" on a working wlan0 (connected) interface](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/connect-network-is-unreachable-on-a-working-wlan0-connected-interface)

However, if I try the poster's solution of adding a missing Gateway IP with the following command:

`sudo route add default gw (my ip)`, I will still get an error:

`SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`

Does anyone have an idea of what the problem could be? Thank you!

Comment: Did you restart networking?

Comment: Is the "(my ip)" part the address of your router, or your local machine? It should be your router's address, i.e. the thing that connects you to the internet.

Comment: Put your ip, or even better, put your `route -n` command output and let us know what is the ip of your gateway. We will give you the direction to follow!