# RPi2: Python requests fails for https (Errno 101)

Tags: raspbian, python, networking, ssh, connection

I'm trying to make my first web scraper and keep getting errors for https URLs but not http.

I am running Python 2.7.9 on RPi2 with Raspbian Jessie. I am also SSHing into the Pi on my laptop. All of this is being done at my home network.

I do not get these errors when running the code below on my laptop. Only when running it on RPi2.

I tried to find some solutions online and I found some people talking about issues with the proxy, but not sure if it applies here.

```
>>> import requests
>>> page = requests.get("http://www.google.com")
>>> page.status_code
200
>>> page = requests.get("https://www.timeanddate.com")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 508, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.timeanddate.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x764fbd90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable',))
```

Comment: try  urllib3 , sudo pip install urllib3 --upgrade

Comment: It says requirements are already up to date when I run that.

Comment: Are you using ipv6 by any chance?

Comment: I do not think so, but I followed these instructions (https://bneijt.nl/blog/post/enable-ipv6-on-your-raspberry-pi/) to enable it. Hmmmm although before all of this, I gave my RPi2 a static IP. Does that have something to do with it?

Comment: I accidentally cut off some of the output error message and have added it to my OP

Comment: The solution to my problem is provided here:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14101/connect-network-is-unreachable-on-a-working-connected-wlan0-interface

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are having timeout issues. Here is an example of 1 second timeout, which is working fine.

```
import requests

from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
try:
   r = requests.get("https://www.timeanddate.com", timeout=1)
   print r.status_code
   print r.headers
   print r.encoding
   print r.text
except ConnectionError as e:
   print e
   r = "No response"
```

Comment: I tried your code and I get the following output: `HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.timeanddate.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded                                                    with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConn                                                   ection object at 0x7645f910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101]                                                    Network is unreachable',))`   Using a longer timeout value doesn't help either.

Comment: do they even have port=443 open?

Comment: I just followed instructions here (https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-check-if-port-443-is-open) and it looks like port 443 is open for timeanddate.com

Comment: remove it. Use my code then work from there

Comment: Remove what? I was using your code earlier. I didn't specifically use port 443 or anything. That error message is the result from using your code.

Comment: strange. Is it in a new blank file? also can you ping the www.timeanddate.com ? or are you behind a proxy?

Comment: All of this being done at home and I don't believe I'm behind a proxy. Your code works fine on my laptop. However, I'm trying to run this on my Raspberry Pi 2 -- I'm SSHing into it on my laptop. I have run your code in interactive mode and as a script, but I still get the same error. I recently setup a static IP on the RPi2 for SSHing. Might that have something to do with this error?

Comment: Hmm I get "network is unreachable" if I try to ping websites from RPi2. On the other hand, I can get your code to work for http websites (eg google.com), just not https.

Comment: ah nevermind i figured it out and posted the answer as a comment under the OP

Answer (score 1):

From the

> Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 101] Network is
>   unreachable

error message, it seems that you are not able to connect to the server.
Check that you can reach *www.timeanddate.com* on port 443 (HTTPS):

```
$ curl -I https://www.timeanddate.com
```

If you get something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
(...)
```

then there may be some problem with your python installation.
Else, you may have network issues. How is your PI connected to the internet?

Answer (score -1):

I would try running : sudo pip install requests —upgrade

Comment: No luck. I'm now using latest version of requests (2.18.4) and still getting same error.

Comment: do you have the latest openssl packages installed aswell ?

Comment: yes i believe so. I have version `1.0.1t-1+deb8u6`. I have also already ran `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.